# .net : smart way to deserialize a json with a varying number of identical objects but not part of an array?

Tags: .net, json

This is not the first time I end up finding a json strings with a large number of identical objects each having a different key and not part of an array and I never found a smart way to deserialize something like this.
Anyone able to suggest an effective way to deserialize the following json?

```
{
  "General": {
    "Code": "ABC",
    "Type": "bla",
    "Name": "anything",
    "CurrencySymbol": "$",
    "CountryName": "USA"
  },
  "Components": {
    "0": {
      "Code": "AAA",
      "Name": "name",
      "Sector": "",
      "Industry": ""
    },
    "1": {
      "Code": "BBB",
      "Name": ""name",
      "Sector": "",
      "Industry": "",
    },
    "2": {
      "Code": "CCC",
      "Name": "name",
      "Sector": "",
      "Industry": "",
    },
    "3": {
      "Code": "DDD",
      "Name": "name",
      "Sector": "",
      "Industry": "",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Standard approach: use Dictionary.

Comment: Would you elaborate more on what you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create set of classes:

```
public class Root
{
    public General General { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Component> Components { get; set; }
}
public class General
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
public class Component
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string Industry { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize like this with Json.Net:

```
var test = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had already tried what you suggest and I've tried even something a little bit different as the following which is I believe more correct for the given json

```
public class IndexComponents
{
    public General General { get; set; }
    public Components Components { get; set; }
}

public class General
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Exchange { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public class Components
{
    public Dictionary<string, Component> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Component>();
}

public class Component
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string Industry { get; set; }
}
```

Nothing worked. Class `General` gets deserialized correctly but the dictionary is always null.

Comment: There is no field named dictionary in json. Of course, you will get null.

Comment: Alexander sorry for getting back to you after so long. Your are perfectly right and what you initially proposed worked perfectly. Thanks!